# Auto-closing Github issues is not working

Tags: github

I never managed to close a Github issue, here is an example that I previously had:

- I have only a `master` branch
- I have an issue `#15`
- I did the following commit message  `ESLint rules updated, this closes issue #15`
- I pushed it and I see the following message in the issue: `sandoche added a commit that referenced this issue 4 minutes ago` but the issue is still opened

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: [*"keywords, followed by an issue number"*](https://help.github.com/en/articles/closing-issues-using-keywords) - the word "issue" is getting in the way, "closes #15" would work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in the comment above:

> "keywords, followed by an issue number" - the word "issue" is getting in the way, "closes #15" would work fine